# Sound card selection

Tags: lubuntu, alsa

I'm looking for a way to select sound card in Lubuntu 12.04 without installing any additional packages like xfce4-mixer (with all of its dependencies). Is there a way to interactively select a sound card with alsa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to switch the audio output on the fly from one sound card to another with ALSA. To define my NuForce sound card as the one to use I created the file ~/.asoundrc with the content

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card N2
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card N2
}
```

where the name N2 comes from the content of the file /proc/asound/cards:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0x93480000 irq 23
 1 [B10            ]: USB-Audio - Benchmark 1.0
                      Texas Instruments Benchmark 1.0 at usb-0000:00:04.0-1, full speed
 2 [N2             ]: USB-Audio - NuForce µDAC 2
                      NuForce NuForce µDAC 2 at usb-0000:00:04.0-3, full speed
```

If I want to change to B10 say, I need to edit ~/.asoundrc and restart the sound application.

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal:

`alsamixer`

Press `s` to select a sound card. `Esc` exits

Comment: OK, I thought the s command only displayed the controls for another sound card rather than selecting it for output. I'll try it when I'm at the computer in question.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. After selecting my USB sound card (named N2) and running `aplay test.wav` the internal sound card is still being used whereas running `aplay -Dhw:N2 test.wav` uses my USB sound card.

Comment: For the purpose of trouble shooting, is there a command which displays the currently selected sound card?

Comment: `pacmd` probably does that. Never acually used it for that though, so I don't know the exact command. Try this: `pacmd help`. I use `pacmd` to set my volume to max in the morning and play music to wake me up: `pacmd set-sink-volume 0 55535`

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I'm using Lubuntu which has no PulseAudio daemon running.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I have another idea but it doesn't quite match your requested parameters. It is non-interactive but should do the trick: [Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#Configuration) or [ALSA Project Asoundrc](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#The_default_plugin).

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. However, adding a ~/.asoundrc file doesn't work but interestingly if I instead add an /etc/asound.conf (with the same content) and run `sudo aplay test.wav` it works as expected. Seems to be some kind of file permission problem.

Comment: It turned out that I actually had a pulseaudio daemon running which was installed with gnome-control-center (when I tried it) but the daemon wasn't removed when I uninstalled the control center. This was the source of my problem.