# Cannot change the sound card in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, alsa

I tried to change the sound to my headset using the answer for this question without success:

[Sound card selection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167394/sound-card-selection)

When I restarted Alsa using the following command:

```
sudo alsactl restore
```

I got the following output:

```
No state is present for card Headset    
Found hardware: "USB-Audio" "USB Mixer" "USB046d:0a0c" "" ""
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
No state is present for card Headset
```

```
andrestoga@andrestoga-Studio-1555:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Intel   ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
               HDA Intel at 0xfc700000 irq 46
andrestoga@andrestoga-Studio-1555:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Intel   ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
               HDA Intel at 0xfc700000 irq 46
 1 [Headset ]: USB-Audio - Logitech USB Headset
               Logitech Logitech USB Headset at usb-0000:00:1d.1-1, full speed
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`?

Comment: andrestoga@andrestoga-Studio-1555:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xfc700000 irq 46
andrestoga@andrestoga-Studio-1555:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xfc700000 irq 46
 1 [Headset        ]: USB-Audio - Logitech USB Headset
                      Logitech Logitech USB Headset at usb-0000:00:1d.1-1, full speed

Comment: What did you change between those two outputs?

Comment: Oh, sorry, in the first output my headset was unplug. I didn't know I included it.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo alsactl nrestore`?