# I dont have sound

Tags: drivers, sound, 18.04, realtek

Hi I currently can't hear anything on my netbook,  I'm running lubuntu 18.04. when I open alsamixer it says:
[imagen de alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF8kP.png)

as you can see it recognize my sound card which is  Realtek ALC259 but it uses  HDA Intel as a driver so I can't hear anything, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: master volume level is 00 ?

Comment: put it at 100 still no sound

Comment: if pulseaudio is not installed, try installig pulse audio first. It has way easier handling than alsamixer. If you are missing sound in VLC or any other program where you can select which soundcard to use than select the soundcard to use within that software. If you want firefox to be using the soundcard, things become difficult, because you need to change the default soundcard to the one you want to use. There are workarounds to achieve this, but none is perfect. https://askubuntu.com/questions/167394/sound-card-selection and http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is run this command in terminal and see if you now can hear :

```
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

and if it worked for you, you need to run it whenever you login into the system :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "snd-hda-intel" >> /etc/modules'
```

and for more info about sound's problems you can checkout my answer here :
[Headphones not detected when plugged before boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894538/headphones-not-detected-when-plugged-before-boot/1045461#1045461)

**UPDATE**
when you opened your alsamixer please press "**s**" and select your sound card then it will work probably

Comment: doesn't work, maybe its a bug because this is the lastest release?

Comment: I updated my answer a little pls check it again :)

Comment: It doesn't work, one think I noticed is that everytime I start linux I have to select manually the sound card with S, is like it doesn't save the changes, maybe that's one of the reasons?

Comment: when you pressed "s" then your sound worked ? if yes there are some ways to do it when your linux starts

Comment: No it doesn't any ideas?

Comment: sorry I don't know more than this :(